# Div containing facebook like and share button twice as width

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to get the div that contains the Facebook like and share button and the text inside displaying how many people liked it to be as wide as everything that's inside, but the width of the div is twice as wide as whatever is being displayed inside, even though I displayed it to inline-block.

```
.fb-like {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
bottom: -22px;
float: right;
}

<div class='fb-like' data-href='' data-layout='standard' data-action='like' data-show-faces='false' data-share='true'></div>
```

Comment: can you post a sample fiddle, so that someone can assist you. Since there the float and display prop wont work while using position:absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a fixed `width` for your `div`?

```
.fb-like {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: -22px;
    float: right;
    width: 100px; // added, change value to what you need it to be
}
```

Comment: That won't help since facebook display different texts depending on your status. Such as when you're login or not, whether you liked it or not, and so on and so forth.